# Do we know which sea Jesus calmed?

Tags: life-of-jesus, miracles, gospel-of-luke

Preparing for a service at our church, I was reading Luke 8:22-25 when Jesus was asleep in the boat, is woken by his disciples and calms the storm. The same story is also told in Mark 4:35-41 and Matthew 8:23-27.

I had always assumed that Jesus and the disciples are on the Sea of Galilee, however it never says what sea they are crossing. Although not the greatest source ever, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calming_the_storm) also says it happened on the Sea of Galilee.

My question is, how do we know that it is the Sea of Galilee? And if it isn't, is there other alternatives that it could be?

Comment: Looking at a map there are probably 3 sea's big enough to put a boat in: Sea of Galilee, Dead Sea (Salt Sea) or Lake Huleh

Comment: Or the Med :)  except, as BenMiller points out, the Gerasenes are only on the Sea of Galilee

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The next verse, [Luke 8:26](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=luke%208:26&version=NIV), places the event:

> They sailed to the region of the Gerasenes, which is across the lake
>   from Galilee.

Galilee is on the west side of the Sea of Galilee, which means that the [Gerasenes](http://www.blueletterbible.org/search/Dictionary/viewTopic.cfm?topic=IT0003750) were likely on the east side.

Comment: doh. Was trying to place the event by reading earlier verses instead of later verses. Thanks